How to solve Invalid type when using marshmallow to validate a list of nested fields?
I have a Flask application where I use marshmallow schemas to validate my requests, as presented below:
class HyperParameterSchema(Schema):
    name = fields.Str(required=True)
    data_type = fields.Str(required=True)
    default_value = fields.Str(required=True)


class LearnerRequestSchema(Schema):
    files = fields.Raw(type="file")
    name = fields.Str(required=True)
    description = fields.Str(required=True)
    supervision_scope = fields.Enum(SupervisionScope, by_value=True, required=True)
    task_type = fields.Enum(TaskType, by_value=True, required=True)
    tool = fields.Enum(Tool, by_value=True, required=True)
    learner_family_id = fields.Int(required=True)
    hyperparams = fields.List(
        fields.Nested(HyperParameterSchema, many=True),
    )

When I perform requests like the following:
response = requests.post(
    url="http://localhost:8080/api/learners",
    data={
        "name": "some_name",
        "description": "some_description",
        "supervision_scope": "supervised",
        "task_type": "classification",
        "tool": "scikit-learn",
        "learner_family_id": 1,
        "hyperparams": json.dumps(
            [
                {"name": "alpha", "data_type": "float", "default_value": "0.1"},
                {"name": "l1_ratio", "data_type": "float", "default_value": "0.1"},
            ]
        ),
    },
    files={
        "file": open("path_to_file", "rb")
    },
    headers=headers,
)

I keep getting as response b'{"errors":{"form":{"hyperparams":{"0":["Invalid type."]}}}}\n'.
Shouldn't the validation works the way it is implemented? Could somebody help me find out what I might be doing wrong? Thanks!
Currently, I'am using a fields.Raw class to deal with the problem related above:
class LearnerRequestSchema(Schema):
    files = fields.Raw(type="file")
    name = fields.Str(required=True)
    description = fields.Str(required=True)
    supervision_scope = fields.Enum(SupervisionScope, by_value=True, required=True)
    task_type = fields.Enum(TaskType, by_value=True, required=True)
    tool = fields.Enum(Tool, by_value=True, required=True)
    learner_family_id = fields.Int(required=True)
    hyperparams = fields.Raw()

The issue is that I have to manually deserialize the hyperparams field in order to check that desired fields are present, while in the former approach I would get the validation out of the box.

Marshmallow is expecting a list of lists for hyperparams as you have set many=True in the Nested field, and wrapped it in a List field.
You can either remove the list or the many=True as they're both doing the same thing. Either of the below should work for what you're trying to achieve. I prefer fields.Nested(MySchema, many=True) myself.
class LearnerRequestSchema(Schema):
...
    hyperparams = fields.List(
        fields.Nested(HyperParameterSchema)
    )

class LearnerRequestSchema(Schema):
...
    hyperparams = fields.Nested(HyperParameterSchema, many=True)

